# Getting JavaSE-1.7 to work with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java

OK, so, I have Java installed. And the JDK from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html and my `jre7` folder is in `C:\Program Files\Java`. That kind of thing, and when I go to Eclipse, I get this:

[image]

Where is JavaSE-1.7? I have 1.6 I guess... I am trying to download jdk7 but appearntly, I already have it installed.

I run Windows 7 (32-bit). Please help?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? The most recent (Juno) comes with Java 7 support built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 7 support for Eclipse is not part of the Indigo release (which it looks like you are running). I believe you have to [download](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) a recent build of Eclipse to get Java 7 support.

For more details, refer to

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Java7
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_7_Support_%28BETA%29

Comment: But I've seen screenshots of Eclipse ... where it said "xecution environemnt JRE" to say "JavaSE-1.7" ... so I wonder... what do I do?

Comment: Looks like you didn't visit the links.

Comment: I did, thanks. But I just said why I saw what I saw. Please don't assume.

Comment: According to the last link, Java 7 support was pulled out of beta, and they have more recent builds of Eclipse that you will have to download in order to get support for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Java 7 support has been around for some time in Indigo SR1.

http://eclipse.org/org/press-release/20110929_indigosr1.php

What you do is;

Configure a "default jre"
 or
Configure a "project specific jre"

(Then click some buttons that looks relevant:  http://xkcd.com/627/)

Then you might also need to change the java compiler level setting in the projects properties.